# Strategies for handling categorical features for decision trees?

Tags: machine-learning, decision-tree, feature-selection, categorical-data

At a node, for categorical features, I'm currently trying all (2^m -2)/2 possible ways to split the m distinct values of feature into two groups. All samples with the same value for a feature are moved together as a group when considering that feature.

The problem is, when m is 35 (countries, for example), I'm going to have to try 17 trillion splits.

Any alternative ways to handle categorical features?

Comment: Search for "Partitioning Nominal Attributes in Decision Trees" by Don Coppersmith et al. (Yes, this is _the_ [Don Coppersmith](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don_Coppersmith). :-)

Answer (score 0):

http://uk.mathworks.com/help/stats/splitting-categorical-predictors-for-multiclass-classification.html?s_tid=gn_loc_drop describes this very problem. In short:

- if this is a binary classification problem, order the m values according to the average response for this category, then try the m-1 ways to split this sequence.
- else, the link only describes heuristics, including the one by Coppersmith, Hong, and Hosking. A classic one is dummification: just try m splits, each consisting of one value to the right branch and m-1 values to the left branch.

Comment: Yes, I'm doing binary classification. I don't quite understand what this means "The tree can order the categories by mean response (for regression) or class probability for one of the classes (for classification). Then, the optimal split is one of the L – 1 splits for the ordered list."  Since I'm not doing regression, I'd be ordering the m values by the class probability? What is it and how do I calculate such a probability?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what this means :"order the m values according to the average response for this category"?

Comment: For binary classification, the response can be encoded as 0 or 1. For each of the m values, compute the average of the response for all samples where the feature is taking this value. This is a real in [0,1]. Order the m values according to those reals.